# Invalid route name: 'users/:columnname_index' - Can't rollback, change column name, nor display some pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing, routes, migration

I created a migration to add a Urlname column to Users table. Then I added an index to the migration. Here's the resulting migration:

```
class AddUrlnameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :urlname, :string
    add_index :users, :urlname, :unique => true
  end
end
```

Then I used rake db:migrate.

schema.rb contains the 'urlname' column & says it has a unique index. However, certain pages on my site have errors: Invalid route name: 'users/:urlname_index'.

Fine, I don't want to call it 'urlname' anyway. I want to call it 'permalink'. But now I can't generate a FixColumnName migration, a RemoveUrlNameFromUsers, nor can I rollback - same "Invalid route name: 'users/:urlname_index'" error for all three.

So I removed `add_index :users, :urlname, :unique => true` from the migration file, even though I had already migrated it. That didn't help.

My routes.rb contains

```
Crowdpublishtv::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  #resources 'users/:urlname', :to => 'User#booklist'
  #match 'users/:urlname_index', :to => 'users#show'

  devise_for :users
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => "users#booklist"
  end

  get "attachments/show"

  resources :users do
    resources :books
  end

  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'booklist', 'blog', 'profileinfo', 'readerprofileinfo', 'orgprofileinfo'
    end
  end
 end
```

I tried commenting out & uncommenting out the lines that are marked with #. Didn't help.

Here's the relevant db:migrate status:

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20130319002105  Create users
   up     20130328235904  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20130703205730  Add devise to users
   up     20130911002912  Add bookfiles to users
   up     20130917143106  Add urlname to users
```

The ****NO FILE**** was something I thought I had rolled back... But since it was long before 'Add urlname to users,' I'm pretty sure it's irrelevant.

Any insight as to what is incorrect? I'm on rails 3.1.0, ruby 1.9.2, with sqlite3, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lot of devise_for :users in the routes.rb. Make sure you have only one and also the order of it matters

Make sure to put your resources :users below the devise_for :users route.

as explained here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface

Comment: Most of the devise_for code in routes.rb was automatically generated when I installed the Devise gem. That code has been in the routes.rb file for the past two months with no problem. It's the Urlname that's giving me problems.

Comment: I take that back. It was the devise_for code that mattered. Don't know why it suddenly became a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your error says "Invalid route name" so you should look at your routes, not at the db index.

As vigneshre pointed out, you have multiple devise_for in your routes. Devise doesn't generate all of them and my guess is your ran the devise generator multiple times (if that's how they got there).

Delete the routes you aren't using and condense the ones you are.

Your question isn't entirely clear and it's hard to tell what triggered your errors. You seem to be asking about many different problems all at once.

1. Changing your migration files does nothing if they are already run. Migration files are just scripts that are run against your database and then left alone. Your schema_migrations table makes a record of what was run. Once the file has been run, you can do the "down" version of the script to rollback changes, but changing the file to remove a line has no impact on your system.
2. Cleanup the routes. The guides on routing may help you understand it better http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Does that help?

Comment: Looks like cleaning up devise allowed rollback to work. I have no idea why that was the issue & would've never found it myself.